# Visual Studio Code malfunctions (not reporting errors, no suggestions etc.)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quite often I experience problems using VS code.
At some point it reports errors where there aren't really any but misses existing errors.
Also suggestions don't come; the blue baloon simply never shows up. Find references etc does not work either. Basically nothing that an IDE should help you with works. Rebuilding & reopening sometimes helps but not always. Manually opening a file using ctrl+p and filename makes it being recognized by VS Code again so that references can be resolved. I know a few other people with the same problem - any suggestions? If I cannot fix this, I am better of with VS or Notepad++ ...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was caused by having to much sources (node_modules) scanned what then must have somehow crashed analyzing. updating tsconfig.json solved this issue:
"exclude": ["node_modules/**/*"]
(root level)